# How can I export values from a database and echo all it separated by an &lt;hr /&gt;, except the first and the last results?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How can I export values from a database and echo all it separated by an <hr />, except the first and the last results??

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT `title`, `content` FROM `news` ORDER BY title ASC");
$stmt->execute(array($category));
foreach($stmt as $row){
    echo "<p>" . $row['title'];
    echo $row['content'] . "</p> <hr />";
}
```

it outputs:

```
<p>title1
content1</p>
<hr>
<p>blabla
blabla</p>

<!--My question is how to remove this hr-->
<hr>
```

I tried to use a for cicle, but it didn't work.

thanks in advance

Comment: You can use [rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) to get the number of results and with a simple `for` loop you should be able to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT `title`, `content` FROM `news` ORDER BY title ASC");
$stmt->execute(array($category));

$numResults = $stmt->rowCount();
$counter = 0;
foreach($stmt as $row){
  echo "<p>" . $row['title'];

if (++$counter == $numResults) {
        // last row
        echo $row['content'] . "</p>";
    } else {
        // not last row
        echo $row['content'] . "</p> <hr />";
    }
}
```

That will count the rows up till the last one, and skip writing the HR for that one.